# Textarea not submitting on enter

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I know that this question is probably redundant, but after having looked through almost every related question on stackoverflow, I still haven't been able to make my problem "go away." The problem is this:

On key press of "enter", submit textarea contents instead of creating a new line.

This is what I am working with:
The jQuery (an answer from a similar question on here):

```
  $('#message').keypress(function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13){
      $('#form').submit();
    }
  });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="message">
<form name="form" class="form" id="form" action="chatsendmesg.php" method="POST">
<textarea rows="2" name="message" id="message" class="message" placeholder="RM911 Chat" cols="26"></textarea>
<input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

Even with this code, the key press of "enter" still creates a new line instead of the submit. What on earth am I not understanding here?? Is it a lack of a `preventDefault`?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Why use a textarea then if you only want one line, use `<input type="text">` instead which handles `enter` as a form submit by default

Comment: You didn't tell us what the problem was. Error message? JS Console error? Doesn't do anything? Details help.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - For visual purposes so that the user can see their entire message in a more "text-editor" kind of way. Otherwise I would definitely use the `input type="text"` method!

Comment: Could always use css to just make the text field bigger `<input type="text" style="width:200px; height:75px" />` and other styles to make it look how you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
             $("#message").keypress(function(e){
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13){
                      $("#form1").submit();   
                }
              });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <form name="form1" class="form1" id="form1" action="chatsendmesg.php" method="post">
          <textarea rows="2" name="message" id="message" class="message" placeholder="RM911 Chat" cols="26"></textarea> 
          <input id="submit1" class="submit1" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit1" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work (although I agree it should). Here is all the components (minus PHP obviously) that I am dealing with: (http://jsfiddle.net/6bQj6/). On that fiddle, the script does not work.

Comment: Have you noticed I changed the Id & Name of Form & TextArea in my above code? The code I gave above works. I checked your fiddle and changed it... here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/HaveArun/6bQj6/1/

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` will not work because for a textarea, the default action is to put the character (represented by the key stroke) in the text area. That is, none of your keystrokes will make it into the text area.

To prevent only the new line from being entered into the text area, you need to stop propagation of the `keypress` event, but only when the key pressed is ENTER, like this:

```
$("#void").keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13){
      $('#form').submit();
      return false;  // stop propagation of the keypress
    }
   return true;
});
```