# Input field not submitting on enter press

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a problem with submitting a input field. I know I am not the first one who ask this question but I looked at the answers and they didn't work.

I have an input field and a submit button inside a div. I have the code working so that you can search on button press but I can't get submitting on enter press working.

html:

```
<div class="search singers" action="templates/search/search_singer.php" method="POST">
                <input name="search" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search here for singers" onkeyup="autosug();" data-file="search_singers"/><input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search();"/>
    <div id="output" class="output">

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
var link = '#search';

//post input
$(function(){
  $(link).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(link).submit();
        //He detect an enter press but stops then
      }
  });
});
```

I found the Jquery code on [this site](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter)
And here a similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857179/textarea-not-submitting-on-enter)

**problem sovled** I came at the idea that I have a function that makes the ajax request to send the data to php. I now call that function on enter press.

Comment: is this only your html code or you forget  to submit your whole code?

Comment: Take a look now. I added the overall div of the input field

Comment: where is your form tag???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should be like this. You forgot the form tag in your code, and that's why the form won't submit.

```
<div class="search singers">
 <form name='your  form' action="templates/search/search_singer.php" method="POST">
      <input name="search" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search here for singers" onkeyup="autosug();" data-file="search_singers"/>
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
        <div id="output" class="output">

        </div>
    </div>
```

And  second thing your autonsan function like this

```
<script>
function autosug() {
    alert("You you are here");
}
</script>
```

Comment: But when I do this excaclly like you I get the error that the page declared as action is not found. When I clear the action the autosuggest still works but the search not.

Comment: remove your onclick="search();" function from submit button

Comment: MY autosug functions contains the xml request code and my search function contains the xml request for searching

Comment: you can write your xml contain code inside your autosug function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a form. So when you will press enter, then form will be submitted including input field value.

```
<div class="search singers">
    <form action="templates/search/search_singer.php" method="POST">
        <input name="search" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search here for singers" onkeyup="autosug();" data-file="search_singers"/>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search();"/>
    </form>
    <div id="output" class="output">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not worked with js, but if you please enter, this form will be submitted. You have used action in div, which is invalid.